# Merge two arrays with random key indexes and then sort by the key index

Tags: php, arrays

Say you have these two arrays:

```
$a = array( 
  1 => 'This should be position #1 in merged array' 
);

$b = array( 
  0 => 'This should be position #0 in merged array',
  2 => 'This should be position #2 in merged array',
);
```

How can you end up with a new array that looks like this:

```
$merged_a_b = array( 
  0 => 'This should be position #0 in merged array',
  1 => 'This should be position #1 in merged array',
  2 => 'This should be position #2 in merged array',
);
```

I tried `array_merge( $a, $b )`, but it changes the key indexes and results in this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'This should be position #0 in merged array' (length=42)
  1 => string 'This should be position #2 in merged array' (length=42)
  2 => string 'This should be position #1 in merged array' (length=42)
```

As you can see, the values are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to preserve the keys, you can use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php):

```
$a = array( 
    1 => 'This should be position #1 in merged array' 
);
$b = array( 
    0 => 'This should be position #0 in merged array',
    2 => 'This should be position #2 in merged array',
);
array_replace($a, $b);
```

And then use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort according to keys:

```
ksort($a);
```

Comment: That results in the key indexes not being lost, but the final array is still unordered, it'd be 0, 2, 1. Is there a way to then re-sort them by the key index?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `+` operator then the `ksort` function:

```
$a = array( 
  1 => 'This should be position #1 in merged array' 
);

$b = array( 
  0 => 'This should be position #0 in merged array',
  2 => 'This should be position #2 in merged array',
);

$merged = $a + $b;
ksort($merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same variable using `+=` assignment operator to merge multiple arrays in a single variable as below. after you can use `ksort` function to reorder array keys and its values.

```
$array = array( 
  1 => 'This should be position #1 in merged array' 
);
$array += array( 
  0 => 'This should be position #0 in merged array',
  2 => 'This should be position #2 in merged array',
);
ksort($array);
```